# make an uisegmentedcontrol in an uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to use a very large segmentedcontrol component so I had the idea to make it in a uiscrollview ..so by scrolling horizontally user can choose the appropriate item.
I wrote this code:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + kLeftMargin, rect.size.height - kPaletteHeight - kTopMargin, 2*rect.size.width , kPaletteHeight);
seg.frame = frame;

scroll.frame = frame;
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width * 2,frame.size.height);
scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scroll.scrollsToTop = NO;
[scroll addSubview:seg];
```

but the scroll view didn't let the segmentedcontrol to be seen.
where was my mistake?

Comment: having the same problem! What was your final decision?

Comment: i am having an issue with mine,  I can see my segmented control and i can scroll horizontally, but i can't select a segment which wasn't displayed when created.  anyone?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this will help you:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 435)];
 scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
 scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

 NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
 UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
 segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
 segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
 segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

 [scroll addSubview:segmentedControl];
 [segmentedControl release]; 
 [self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView to scroll horizontally and use buttons as cells.

Comment: True, the question dates from 2010..many things changed ..one of them is that now we have UICollectionView :)